# Asking for help breaking down a piece of code --- Head First Python 2nd Edition (11/9/2022) pg 102

Tags: python

https://prnt.sc/B4pFd_w5reM0
<<< photo of page

https://prnt.sc/bfCN6MN3P9DM
<<< screenshot of code

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': 'python',
}

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(f"Hi {name.title()}.")

    if name in friends:
        language = favorite_languages[name].title()
        print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")
```

I am not sure why `[name]` is in brackets instead of language. We are interested in the language they prioritize and not who the person is (for the value 'language' in specific at least). So I am wondering why the brackets have 'name' inside them, and not 'language'.

Also.... could someone breakdown what is happening in this code? I think I am just lost in general.

First we have a dictionary called favorite_languages
first column are keys, second column are values

going down, we have a list called friends, I think the words inside are called values.

`for name in favorite_languages.keys():`
this line of code says tells the editor? right? that the keys (first column), each of the keys will be categorized as a 'name'. correct? the keys in the dictionary (named favorite_languages).

`print(f"Hi {name.title()}.")`
line of code says we will print a message. Hi (with a name pulled from the dictonary with the first letter capitalized by the (`.title()` command) Just not sure how to describe the f... all I know is that it is needed... and that it exists.

`if name in friends:`
as the names from the dictonary get pulled, this line of code tells the editor to check if the name pulled is identical to one of the values in the list 'friends'.

`language = favorite_lanugages[name].title()`
this is where I am stuck. the name pulled from the dictionary, is the same as the value in the list.... so we tell the editor to put the name back into the dictonary... we find the value that is next to it? and then that value gets its first letter capitalized and becomes known as the value 'language'? or is it a variable? and not a value...

`print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")`
coming back full circle. We are going to print on a new line. The message starts with the name we pulled from the dictionary that is also identical to a value found in the list. The name has it's first letter capitalized. Text is added ', I see you love '. Then we add the value we created earlier called 'lanugage' and add an exclaimation point after it. Close the quotation marks and close the parenthesis.

What did I miss? Is my thought process right or wrong? Am I on the right track?

Comment: I dont understand. How would you focus the question? @shadowtalker

Comment: You are asking several questions at once here. That's not considered good practice on this site, because it makes the question(s) hard to answer, and it makes the information less useful for other people.

Comment: Instead of asking for a clarification and a breakdown, I should seperate into two posts right?

Comment: I think it's okay as-is. I am writing an answer.

Comment: I just noticed that you got this code snippet from a book. You might want to review the material in the book that describes how dictionaries work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are asking several questions at once, so I will answer them one at a time.

I will preface my answer by saying this:

Python is a programming language. A programming language consists of instructions that are provided to a computer program. The computer program simply reads one instruction at a time, and performs some work according to the contents of the instruction. Therefore, programming languages have **strict rules** about every operation that they support. The programming language provides a set of operations that it supports, and we build programs by combining those operations.

Moreover, programs need to be converted from text into a version of those instructions that the computer understands. Therefore the text must also follow a specific and clearly-defined **syntax**. The meaning of something like `[]` is and must be unambiguous, otherwise it would be impossible for the computer to interpret our programs.

The important conclusion here is that computer programs must be expressed in a specific way, and that every piece of text has a specific purpose and meaning. Python does not and cannot ever understand what your intentions are. Programming consists of taking your ideas and translating them into the specific operations and syntax provided by the programming language.

I write this because you seem to be taking an *interpretive* approach to reading code, and you seem to be lacking the fundamental knowledge required to understand it properly. You seem to be trying to guess at the meaning of code by broadly matching it up to how it looks in English. As nice as it is that Python looks like plain English text, it is *not* plain English text. It is a programming language like any other, and its rules are as strict as any other. **If you don't know what something means, resist the temptation to guess at what it means.**

I strongly suggest finding a structured learning resource, such as an online course or a book. It will guide you through all of the concepts, syntax elements, and data types that you will need to learn programming. You *must* learn what these things are. You will never be able to read or write code by interpreting and guessing based on visual patterns.

---

> I am not sure why `[name]` is in brackets instead of language. We are interested in the language they prioritize and not who the person is (for the value 'language' in specific at least). So I am wondering why the brackets have 'name' inside them, and not 'language'.

It is in brackets because the names are the *keys* of the dictionary. The `favorite_languages` is a lookup table from names to languages. It is not a lookup table from languages to names.

In general, a dictionary is a one-way lookup table. The things on the left of `:` are the "keys", and the things on the right are the "values". The keys must be unique, but the values can be non-unique. The `[]` syntax performs lookups from keys to values only.

What you are "interested in" is relevant only insofar as it is the goal of your program. You do not get to choose what `[]` means, based on what you are interested in. Its meaning is built into Python and cannot be changed without modifying Python itself. You must use the tools that you are given, and cannot use tools that do not exist.

> first we have a dictionary called favorite_languages first column are keys, second column are values

It's not helpful to think of a dictionary as "columns", like a spreadsheet. Think of it as a lookup table. That's why it's called a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are like words in a traditional dictionary, and the values are like definitions.

It is important to have a clear understanding of what dictionaries do. Otherwise you won't understand when or how to use them, and you won't understand code that uses them. That might be what is happening here.

> going down, we have a list called friends, I think the words inside are called values.

This is a somewhat different usage of the term "value".

Outside the context of dictionaries, "value" does not have a strict technical meaning. The word is usually used to distinguish values, which are tangible *things*, from variables, which are placeholders for things and do not mean anything on their own.

So when we talk about the *values* in a list, we are just talking about the things inside the list. People also use the word *elements* to mean the same thing.

> editor? right?

I assume you are talking about an "editor" as in a "text editor" or "code editor". No. That's just a program that you use to edit text. It does not run your code. Some code editors like VS Code have built-in features that help you write code. But your code never "tells" your text editor anything. The code exists to be interpreted by Python. Anything else is just an attempt to help you write the code.

> `for name in favorite_languages.keys():` this line of code says tells the editor? right? that the keys (first column), each of the keys will be categorized as a 'name'. correct? the keys in the dictionary (named favorite_languages).

No. This code does not categorize anything.

The `.keys()` method accesses the keys of a dictionary (as explained above). This loops over `favorite_languages.keys()` and assigns the looped values to `name`.

The syntax `for x in things:` loops over the elements of `things`. It assigns the first element to `x`, then runs the code in the block, then assigns the second element to `x`, then runs the code in the block, etc. Loops are an essential tool in programming, and it is very important that you spend time on understanding how they work and how to use them.

> `print(f"Hi {name.title()}.")`

Your understanding seems correct.

`name` is the key from `favorite_languages.keys()`, because of `for name in favorite_languages.keys():`. We also happen to know that this corresponds to people's names.

> `if name in friends:`

Correct. `name in friends` is an expression that returns `True` if and only if the value of `name` is equal to one of the elements in `friends`.

The `if` then executes the code inside the block if and only if the result is `True` (or is equivalent to `True` in a specific sense that you don't need to worry about right now).

> `language = favorite_languages[name].title()`

This code does *not* put anything back into the dictionary. This code does not operate by finding values "next to" anything.

`favorite_languages` is a dictionary, i.e. a lookup table. This code uses the value of `name` to look up a language in `favorite_languages`.

Finally, it assigns the result to the `language` variable. From the perspective of Python, this variable is completely unrelated to the `favorite_languages`. It is a completely separate placeholder.

The fact that they both say "languages" is relevant to you, the reader and programmer, but not relevant to Python.

> `print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")`

`\t` is a *tab* characdter, not a new line.

Otherwise yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: There, I made it Community Wiki, so you are free to vandalize it if you wish.

Comment: "favorite_languages is a dictionary, i.e. a lookup table. This code uses the value of name to look up a language in favorite_languages." The way I understood it is that you are looking up the name in the dictionary... with no additional step to attain the language.... with the end result GETTING the language... that was one of my disconnects.

Comment: because in my head... i saw it was looking up the name... and assigning the result to the language variable. Except I understood that it should of assigned the names for ex: jen, sarah, as the languages INSTEAD of python for ex. And that is wrong. I know. Yet when I put it into code... it works... and outputs python. Still coming to grips. Thinking out loud.